# Comparing color strings in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to compare the following color strings with each other, i am using localeCompare for this and here we have the following colors:
'yellow', 'green', 'white' and transparent. These are saved in the variable 'status' as shown below.

How can i compare these strings the best way?
Is there some kind of sort order i can set?

```
arr1.sort((a, b) => (a.status != null) ? a.status.localeCompare(b.status) : 0)
```

I tried reversing it but that was pure random stuff, i have trouble understanding this.

arr1 has multiple data stored in it, like

```
name: 'name'
firstName: 'firstname'
status: 'yellow'
```

I have a table which is rendered and in this table we want the yellow once to show first, the green second, white after that and transparent at the end of the table.

1. yellow
2. green
3. white
4. transparent

With the localeCompare, when i do the alphabetic ordering, ofcourse yellow is shown at the end of the list.

Comment: you're currently just sorting alphabetically, if you want some sort of priority see: [How to sort array of objects in JavaScript based on definite attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533823/how-to-sort-array-of-objects-in-javascript-based-on-definite-attribute-value)

Comment: Please create a [mcve] including an example dataset for `arr1`,  explain what output order you get, and what order you expect to get for that data. And if that order should not be alphabetically then explain the rules for the ordering.

Comment: Just edited it with expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be a clear value from the string you could use, how about defining the order yourself:

```
type StatusColor = 'yellow' | 'green' | 'white' | 'transparent';

const colorOrder: Record<StatusColor, number> = {
  yellow: 0,
  green: 1,
  white: 2,
  transparent: 3
};

const exampleStatus: StatusColor[] = ['yellow', 'white', 'transparent', 'green', 'green', 'yellow', 'transparent', 'yellow'];

exampleStatus.sort((a, b) => colorOrder[a] - colorOrder[b]);

console.log(exampleStatus); // [ "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "green", "green", "white", "transparent", "transparent" ]
```